# Rename synched google drive on google only

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I know that google drive depends on ID of folders/files not the name, so You can have multiple folders with same name.

In my Case I have multiple Unity3D projects where I always synch the assets folder, When I want to download on of my projects it takes me time to figure which assets folder on google drive belongs to my project.

Is there any way I can rename the folder on google drive while keeping it on local drive without changing?

Or  any other options can help thanks

Comment: can you add the code you are using for the upload this is definitely possible

Comment: How are you syncing this?

Comment: I am using google drive app to synch

Answer (score 1):

I suggests to add folder in each assets folder and name the file with your project name. Make it all capital and add "000" at the beginning of the folder name to make it at the top of the list for ease find